# How can I convert Japanese date to Western date in java?

Tags: java, date

I have methods like this:

```
//datetime is millisecond
public static String getStringDateFormatMonth(long datetime) {
          String yearlessPattern = "yyyy年MM月";
          SimpleDateFormat yearlessSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(yearlessPattern);
          Date date = new Date(datetime);
          String datestr = yearlessSDF.format(date);
          return datestr;

         }

public static String getStringDateFormat(long datetime) {
          String yearlessPattern = "dd日";
          SimpleDateFormat yearlessSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(yearlessPattern);
          SimpleDateFormat sdfDay = new SimpleDateFormat("E", Locale.JAPAN);
          Date date = new Date(datetime);
          String datestr = yearlessSDF.format(date) + "(" + sdfDay.format(date) + ")";
          return datestr;

         }
```

Intialize string a:

```
String a = LifelogUtil.getStringDateFormatMonth(currentDate.getTimeInMillis())
                    + LifelogUtil.getStringDateFormat(currentDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

and the result I get is

```
2015年07月19日(日)
```

Now I want to convert this date back to Western date as this format "yyyy-MM-dd" but I can't figure how to do that. Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formate you given is the locale Japanese format, so that you can use the default option. 
For your convenience please refer the java documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html
Try this one

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, new Locale("ja"));
System.out.println(df.parse("2015年07月20日"));
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

output should be like this:

```
Mon Jul 20 00:00:00 IST 2015
2015年07月20日
```

Refer previous ideone answer here [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0W7szq)

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert an Object into a String, work with it and parse it back. Keep the original informtion in the Date object and render the output (read only) where ever you need it:

```
    // use an object internally:
    Date anyDate = new Date();

    // can also be SimpleDateFormat, etc:
    DateFormat japaneseDf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.JAPAN);
    DateFormat germanDf = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.GERMANY);

    // when you need to display it somewhere render it appropriately, not changing the data:
    System.out.println(japaneseDf.format(anyDate));
    System.out.println(germanDf.format(anyDate));
```

Prints out:

```
2015年7月20日 (月曜日)
Montag, 20. Juli 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
        SimpleDateFormat jp= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy年MM月dd日(E)",Locale.JAPAN); //Japan Format
        SimpleDateFormat west = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Western Format
        try{
            Date date = jp.parse(a); //convert the String to date
            System.out.println(west.format(date));//format the date to Western 
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```